# Select top 10 pages with log parser from iis logs

Tags: iis, logparser

Hi
  Could you please let me know query to select top 10 pages from every iis log files using logparser.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all the logs into a directory then run

```
logparser "SELECT cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM *.log GROUP BY cs-uri-stem ORDER BY cnt DESC" -i:IISW3C -o:CSV
```

(This assumes the logs are in W3C format).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543889/286807), here is how to limit the output to 10 records:

```
logparser "SELECT TOP 10 cs-uri-stem, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM *.log GROUP BY cs-uri-stem ORDER BY cnt DESC" -i:IISW3C -o:CSV
```

(This assumes the logs are in W3C format).